# PHP search on keywords

Tags: php, mysql, search, keyword, relevance

I have a table in a database with records containing keywords as well as other data. What would be a logical way to create a search function that would allow people to search based on keywords, and order results based on the number of matched keywords?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysql provide `FULLTEXT` search options. Check this link [mysql full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html). These search results will be sorted according to best match. it also has support for boolean mode and NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE(default). You need to add `FULLTEXT` index on search column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query that will work for you.

```
SELECT *, MATCH (ab,cd) AGAINST ('sample text' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevancy 
FROM table_name 
WHERE MATCH (ab,cd) AGAINST ('sample text' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY relevancy DESC;
```